# Cross-Thread Operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

1st off I am not even sure what a C# `Cross-Thread Operation` is, so seeing this debug message blows my mind from the start - `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'panel1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`  I am just attempting to write to a textbox to show the progress of my procedures.  `Thread.Sleep()` is used in the code below for brevity.  I receive the debug message when my code hits the line `panel1.Controls.Add(txt);`  And here is full code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    private int i = 0;
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();

     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            panel1.Controls.Add(txt);
            MethodOne();
            MethodTwo();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void MethodOne()
    {
        txt.Text = "MethodOne Process Has Begun....." + now;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        txt.Text = "MethodOne Process Has Finished....." + now;
    }
    private void MethodTwo()
    {
        txt.Text = "MethodTwo Process Has Begun....." + now;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        txt.Text = "MethodTwo Has Finished....." + now;
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any further details or more information about how my windows form is set-up.

Comment: I'm not sure how surprising this could be... when you've created a background thread and set it working. As Robert said - controls cannot be accessed from a thread different to what they were created on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access UI controls directly from the BackgroundWorker thread. UI controls are on a separate thread, hence the error. This is not allowed:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Controls.Add(txt);
    ...
}
```

The BackgroundWorker allows you to pass a number (usually representing a percentage), and another object back (it could be anything, such as your text). What I'd recommend is this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    bgw.ReportProgress(33, "MethodOne Process Has Begun.....");
    MethodOne();

    bgw.ReportProgress(66, "MethodTwo Process Has Begun.....");
    MethodTwo();

    bgw.ReportProgress(100, "All Processes Finished.");
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    var statusMessage = e.UserState.ToString();
    // Display statusMessage in an appropriate control, i.e. a Label
}
```

Comment: This probably works too, since `panel1.Controls.Add` is being called from an event that's marshaled on the UI thread.  Note that `progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;` already works.

Comment: Would it be better (or does it even matter) to place the panel1.Controls.Add(txt) under the button1_Click() event or the Form1() event?

Answer (score 1):

Actions that take place on the UI from a different thread require a special marshaling process called an [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx).  An error occurs if you don't use the Invoke from the other thread.

Comment: So the issue is I am attempting to modify my form via the backgroundWorker1_DoWork() procedure?

Comment: Yes.  You should probably be modifying the form on the same thread; I don't see any advantage to modifying the form in a `BackgroundWorker`.  `BackgroundWorker` is intended for long-running operations that don't involve the form (except for a progress indicator which is already thread-safe).  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) for a code example of Invoke.